# Regular Expressions URL

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics

Hi there i have some problem with Regular Expressions 
I'm trying to set funnel goal with Regular Expressions

first step user come to changal.com and then search for near restaurant:

tehran/nezami-ganjavi

**nezami-ganjavi** in this url is neighborhood name and its different for each user based on their location.I have 400 neighborhood name

and then they go to restaurant page:

tehran/nezami-ganjavi/fastfood-charli-behjat-abad-tehran

I want to match the urls which **ends** with  **neighborhood name** not restarunt page. for tracking funnel

Comment: Try `^tehran/([^/]+)$`. Please specify what is specific about neiborhood names so that a better regex can be devised. Are `-` always present there?

Comment: Then try `^tehran/([^/-]+-[^/]+)/?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for helping yes always there is - .  but your Regular Expressions does not work http://regexr.com/3g85p

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just want to match the url for search result of near restaurant not restarunt page
search result : 
https://changal.com/tehran/nezami-ganjavi
the last part will change 
resto page :
https://changal.com/tehran/nezami-ganjavi/fastfood-charli-behjat-abad-tehran

Comment: You are not testing the patterns correctly. GA does not take the host part, it takes what goes after it. `tehran` will be the starting text. So, you need to test like this - http://regexr.com/3g85s. Note in GA there is no need escaping `/`. To test multiline string at regexr, you need to enable `m` modifier. Regexr uses JS regex, and GA uses RE2. In short: use appropriate tools, and test only in the target environment. Else, your "don't work" comment makes no sense. Try `^tehran/([^/-]+-[^/]+)/?$` or `^tehran/([^/]+)/?$` in GA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great it works thanks a lot now what should I do if I want math :  kish/markaze-shahr  too ? its another city I tried to use |  but doesn't work thanks man

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you need to match 2 cities (tehran and kish) or any city? If any city, replace `tehran` with `[^/]+`, else, try `^(tehran|kish)/([^/]+)/?$` Please let me know which pattern worked for you so that I could post and explain the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that GA regex parsing does not take into account the host part, it takes what goes after it. So, `https://changal.com/` won;t be "visible" for it in `https://changal.com/tehran/nezami-ganjavi`.

Note in GA there is no need escaping `/`. You may use

```
^tehran/([^/-]+-[^/]+)/?$
```

or - if there is no need checking for an obligatory 1 hyphen in the neighborhood:

```
^tehran/([^/]+)/?$
```

or - to match any city:

```
^[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$
```

If your neighborhood value must have at least 1 hyphen, use

```
^[^/]+/([^/-]+-[^/]+)/?$
```

Some notes on the patterns:

- `^` - start of string input
- `[^/]+` - one or more characters (`+`) that are not `/` (note that to match either `tehran` or `kish` you may use an alternation group `(tehran|kish)`)
- `/` - a slash
- `([^/-]+-[^/]+)` - 1+ chars other than `/` and `-` (`[^/-]+`), then a `-`, and then 1+ chars other than `/` (`[^/]+`)
- `/?` - 1 or 0 slashes (an optional slash)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks man yes both of them work at http://regexr.com but I tried to  verify in GA and it said : This Goal would have a 0% conversion rate based on your data from the past 7 days 
and other thing i found some neighborhood name without - like : tehran/valfajr
now we have 2 problem 
thanks man

Comment: You will have to wait before you get enough data. ["You will need to wait a day for conversion rates to be non-zero, assuming you get actual conversion until then."](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69256). We don't have 2 problems. A correct regex for an appropriate problem means no problems at all.

Comment: I know this but these urls are working for 3 months ok lets see and what about second question ? match: tehran/valfajr without - 
thanks

Comment: :) yes we don't have problem your advice works well but i forgot that we have non - utl too

Comment: Look at `^[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$`, it is very generic. It will match a URL with `<ANY_CITY>/ANY_NEIGHBORHOOD`

Comment: I asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780839/how-to-exclude-some-url-from-a-regex-match 
I would be happy if you answer it