# how to exclude some url from a regex match

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics, nsregularexpression

I have 3 type payment ( online, offline, by balance) every payment type have different url so I'm using regex for match all this url :

1- order/checkout/unpaid/done

2- order/checkout/paid/done?Authority=000000000000000000000000000039067905&Status=OK
3- order/checkout/paid/done?Status=OK

regex : (.*?)done

this regex match all of urls but the problem is it match some page too ! kile this product page  :

/tork-**done**r-motahari-tehran

What is the solution ?

Comment: Looks like you just want to match at the end of the string or before a `?`. Try `(.*)done($|[?])`. Not sure you need the first capturing group.

Comment: exactly. its works thanks again please submit your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(.*)done($|[?])
```

The point is that you need to match `done` at the end of the string or at the last `?`. The pattern will match

- `(.*)` - any 0+ characters, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `done` - a literal substring `done`
- `($|[?])` - either `$` (end of string anchor) or a literal `?` (can be written as `\?` in the pattern, the main point being that `?` without brackets or a `\` in front means *1 or 0 repetitions of the atom to the left of the `?`*).

Note that you may turn the groups into non-capturing  by adding `?:` after `(` if you are not using the capturing group values.